# Passing target variables from pattern match to static

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a Makefile to wrap the deployment of an elastic beanstalk app to multiple environments. This is my first time writing an "advanced" makefile and I'm having a bit of trouble.

My goals are as follows:

1. `make deploy` by itself should deploy with `ENVIRONMENT=$(USER)` and `ENV_TYPE=staging`.
2. The environment to deploy to can be set via an environment variable. If `ENVIRONMENT=production` then `ENV_TYPE=production`, otherwise `ENV_TYPE=staging`.
3. As a shorthand for setting the environment variable, one can suffix the `deploy` target with a `-` and the name of the environment. For example: `make deploy-production`.

It's number 3 that is giving me the most trouble. Since any environment not named production is of type staging, I tried to use pattern matching to define the target for deploying to staging environments. Here's what I have currently:

```
ENVIRONMENT = $(USER)
ifeq ($ENVIRONMENT, production)
ENV_TYPE=production
else
ENV_TYPE=staging
endif
DOCKER_TAG ?= $(USER)
CONTAINER_PORT ?= 8000
ES_HOST = logging-ingest.$(ENV_TYPE).internal:80

.PHONY: deploy
deploy:
    -pip install --upgrade awsebcli
    sed "s/<<ES_HOST>>/$(ES_HOST)/" < 01-filebeat.template > .ebextensions/01-filebeat.config
    sed "s/<<DOCKER_TAG>>/$(DOCKER_TAG)/" < Dockerrun.template | sed "s/<<CONTAINER_PORT>>/$(CONTAINER_PORT)/" > Dockerrun.aws.json
    eb labs cleanup-versions --num-to-leave 10 --older-than 5 --force -v --region us-west-2
    eb deploy -v coolapp-$(ENVIRONMENT)

.PHONY: deploy-%
deploy-%: ENVIRONMENT=$*
deploy-%: deploy
    @echo  # Noop required

.PHONY: deploy-production
deploy-production: ENVIRONMENT=production
deploy-production: ENV_TYPE=production
deploy-production: deploy
    @echo  # Noop required
```

The problem is in the last step of the `deploy` target. Namely, `$(ENVIRONMENT)` appears to be unset.

Example Output:

```
18:42 $ make -n deploy-staging
pip install --upgrade awsebcli
sed "s/<<ES_HOST>>/logging-ingest.staging.internal:80/" < 01-filebeat.template > .ebextensions/01-filebeat.config
sed "s/<<DOCKER_TAG>>/schultjo/" < Dockerrun.template | sed "s/<<CONTAINER_PORT>>/8000/" > Dockerrun.aws.json
eb labs cleanup-versions --num-to-leave 10 --older-than 5 --force -v --region us-west-2
eb deploy -v coolapp-
echo  # Noop required
```

Desired Output:

```
18:42 $ make -n deploy-staging
pip install --upgrade awsebcli
sed "s/<<ES_HOST>>/logging-ingest.staging.internal:80/" < 01-filebeat.template > .ebextensions/01-filebeat.config
sed "s/<<DOCKER_TAG>>/schultjo/" < Dockerrun.template | sed "s/<<CONTAINER_PORT>>/8000/" > Dockerrun.aws.json
eb labs cleanup-versions --num-to-leave 10 --older-than 5 --force -v --region us-west-2
eb deploy -v coolapp-staging
echo  # Noop required
```

---

So I have tried to implement Renaud's recursive Make solution, but have run into a minor hiccup. Here's a simplified Makefile that I'm using:

```
ENVIRONMENT ?= $(USER)
ifeq ($ENVIRONMENT, production)
ENV_TYPE = production
else
ENV_TYPE = staging
endif
ES_HOST = logging-ingest.$(ENV_TYPE).internal:80

.PHONY: deploy
deploy:
    @echo $(ENVIRONMENT)
    @echo $(ENV_TYPE)
    @echo $(ES_HOST)


.PHONY: deploy-%
deploy-%:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory ENVIRONMENT=$* deploy
```

When I run `make production`, it looks like the `if` statements surrounding the `ENV_TYPE` definition are not run again. Here's my actual output:

```
12:50 $ make -n deploy-production
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make --no-print-directory ENVIRONMENT=production deploy
echo production
echo staging
echo logging-ingest.staging.internal:80
```

The last two lines should say `production` rather than `staging`, implying there is something wrong with my conditional, but I haven't edited that conditional from earlier versions when it worked, so I'm a but confused. The same error happens if I invoke make with `ENVIRONMENT` set manually (e.g. `ENVIRONMENT=production make deploy`).

Comment: You forgot a set of parens around `$(ENVIRONMENT)` in your `ifeq`.  Try `ifeq ($(ENVIRONMENT), production)`

Comment: I also think you want to define an explicit rule for `deploy-`, otherwise it produces some truly baffling output if you typo the suffix (like `make deploy- production`).

Comment: fml. thanks for catching that! And I will add the `deploy-` target as suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem comes from the way target-specific variable values are inherited by target pre-requisites. What you are trying to do works for explicit target-specific variables:

```
$ cat Makefile
ENVIRONMENT = default

deploy:
    @echo '$@: ENVIRONMENT = $(ENVIRONMENT)'

deploy-foo: ENVIRONMENT = foo
deploy-foo: deploy
    @echo '$@: ENVIRONMENT = $(ENVIRONMENT)'
$ make deploy
deploy: ENVIRONMENT = default
$ make deploy-foo
deploy: ENVIRONMENT = foo
deploy-foo: ENVIRONMENT = foo
```

because the `deploy-foo`-specific `ENVIRONMENT` variable is assigned value `foo` during the first expansion phase (the one during which target-specific variable assignments, target lists and pre-requisite lists are expanded). So, `deploy` inherits this value.

But it does not work with your pattern-specific variables that use the `$*` automatic variable:

```
$ cat Makefile
ENVIRONMENT = default

deploy:
    @echo '$@: ENVIRONMENT = $(ENVIRONMENT)'

deploy-%: ENVIRONMENT = $*
deploy-%: deploy
    @echo '$@: ENVIRONMENT = $(ENVIRONMENT)'
$ make deploy
$ deploy: ENVIRONMENT = default
$ make deploy-foo
deploy: ENVIRONMENT = 
deploy-foo: ENVIRONMENT = foo
```

The reason is that the `deploy-foo`-specific `ENVIRONMENT` variable is what is called a *recursively expanded variable* in make dialect (because you use the `=` assignment operator). It is expanded, recursively, but only when make needs its value, not when it is assigned. So, in the context of `deploy-foo`, it is assigned `$*`, not the pattern stem. `ENVIRONMENT` is passed as is to the context of the `deploy` pre-requisite and, in this context, `$(ENVIRONMENT)` is recursively expanded to `$*` and then to the empty string because there is no pattern in the `deploy` rule. You could try the *simply expanded* (non-recursive) variable flavour:

```
deploy-%: ENVIRONMENT := $*
```

that is immediately expanded, but the result would be the same because `$*` expands as the empty string during the first expansion. It is set only during the second expansion and can thus be used only in recipes (that make expands in a second phase).

A simple (but not super-efficient) solution consists in invoking make again:

```
deploy-%:
    @$(MAKE) ENVIRONMENT=$* deploy
```

Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
ENVIRONMENT = default

deploy:
    @echo '$(ENVIRONMENT)'

deploy-%:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory ENVIRONMENT=$* deploy
$ make
default
$ make deploy
default
$ make deploy-foo
foo
```

Note: GNU make supports a [*secondary expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) and one could think that it can be used to solve this problem. Unfortunately not: the secondary expansion expands only the pre-requisites, not the target-specific variable definitions.

As mentioned above, this recursive make is not very efficient. If efficiency is critical one single make invocation is preferable. And this can be done if you move all your variables processing in the recipe of a single pattern rule. Example if the shell that make uses is bash:

```
$ cat Makefile
deplo%:
    @{ [[ "$*" == "y" ]] && ENVIRONMENT=$(USER); } || \
    { [[ "$*" =~ y-(.*) ]] && ENVIRONMENT=$${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; } || \
    { echo "$@: unknown target" && exit 1; }; \
    echo "$@: ENVIRONMENT = $$ENVIRONMENT" && \
    <do-whatever-else-is-needed>
$ USER=bar make deploy
deploy: ENVIRONMENT = bar
$ make deploy-foo
deploy-foo: ENVIRONMENT = foo
$ make deplorable
deplorable: unknown target
make: *** [Makefile:2: deplorable] Error 1
```

Do not forget to escape the recipe expansion by make (`$$ENVIRONMENT`).

Comment: That's really nice.  I think you want the `ENVIRONMENT = default` to be `?=` instead so that it can be overridden.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Sure, this is just a very simplified example to illustrate the problem. It must be reworked according the OP's specific needs.

Comment: You taught me tons about how make works in this write-up and the comments/corrections to my explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Renaud and lockcm for your answers. I learned a lot about iMake! 

I tried to implement my Makefile with Renaud's recursive Make call solution, as that is the simplest to understand and efficiency is not a big concern in this use case. However, I've run into a weird issue. I will update my question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Due to conversations w/@RenaudPacalet, I have learned that my approach mainly works because the variables defined in the `deploy-%` rules aren't used anywhere but the recipe...where they expand late, just before being passed to the shell.  This lets me use `$*` in the variable definition because the variable definition wont be expanded until the second phase, when `$*` actually has a value.

The method for setting `ENV_TYPE` uses a trick with `patsubst` to produce the condition for an `if` by stripping the word `"production"` from the content of `$ENVIRONMENT`; in this context, an empty string selects the `else` case.  So if `$ENVIRONMENT` is exactly equal to `"production"` then `patsubst` makes an empty string and the `if` evaluates to `production`, otherwise it evaluates to `staging`.

There's an explicit rule at the bottom for `deploy-` because that target would otherwise invoke some crazy implicit pattern rules that tried to compile `deploy-.o`

Finding that made me also consider the other error cases that could arise, so the first few lines define a function to ensure that, if a user specifies both `ENVIRONMENT=X` and uses a suffix `Y`, that there is an appropriate error message (rather than just having the suffix win).  You can see the call to that function as the first line of the `deploy-%` recipe.  There is another potential issue if `$ENVIRONMENT` is defined to have multiple words; the second `deploy:` line implements a test that will error out in this case---it tests that the word-count in `$ENVIRONMENT` is exactly `1` using the same `patsubst/if` trick as above.

It should also be noted that this makefile assumes the real work will be implemented in the recipe under `deploy-%`.

```
# define a function to detect mismatch between ENV and suffix
ORIG_ENV := $(ENVIRONMENT)
ENV_CHECK = $(if $(ORIG_ENV),$(if $(subst $(ORIG_ENV),,$(ENVIRONMENT)),\
   $(error $$ENVIRONMENT differs from deploy-<suffix>.),),)

ENVIRONMENT ?= $(USER)

.PHONY: deploy
deploy: deploy-$(ENVIRONMENT)
deploy: $(if $(patsubst 1%,%,$(words $(ENVIRONMENT))),$(error Bad $$ENVIRONMENT: "$(ENVIRONMENT)"),)

.PHONY: deploy-%
deploy-%: ENVIRONMENT=$*
deploy-%: ENV_TYPE=$(if $(patsubst production%,%,$(ENVIRONMENT)),staging,production)
deploy-%:
        $(call ENV_CHECK)
        @echo  ENVIRONMENT: $(ENVIRONMENT)
        @echo  ENV_TYPE:    $(ENV_TYPE)

# keep it from going haywire if user specifies:
#   ENVIRONMENT= make deploy
# or
#   make deploy-
.PHONY: deploy-
deploy-:
        $(error Cannot build with empty $$ENVIRONMENT)
```

Gives

```
$ USER=anonymous make deploy
ENVIRONMENT: anonymous
ENV_TYPE: staging

$ ENVIRONMENT=production make deploy
ENVIRONMENT: production
ENV_TYPE: production

$ ENVIRONMENT=test make deploy
ENVIRONMENT: test
ENV_TYPE: staging

$ make deploy-foo
ENVIRONMENT: foo
ENV_TYPE: staging

$ make deploy-production
ENVIRONMENT: production
ENV_TYPE: production

$ ENVIRONMENT=foo make deploy-production
Makefile:14: *** $ENVIRONMENT differs from deploy-<suffix>..  Stop.

$ ENVIRONMENT= make deploy
Makefile:24: *** Bad $ENVIRONMENT: "".  Stop.

$ make deploy-
Makefile:24: *** Cannot build with empty $ENVIRONMENT.  Stop.

$ ENVIRONMENT="the more the merrier" make deploy
Makefile:10: *** Bad $ENVIRONMENT: "the more the merrier".  Stop.
```

Reflecting on how this works, it's not simple at all.  There are various interpretations of `$ENVIRONMENT`...for example in the line `deploy: deploy-$(ENVIRONMENT)`, that sense of `$ENVIRONMENT` gets the one that comes in from the shell's environment (possibly being set to `$(USER)` if absent).  There's another sense in the recipe line `@echo  ENVIRONMENT: $(ENVIRONMENT)` which will be the one assigned in `deploy-%: ENVIRONMENT=$*` just above, but after expansion.  I am struck by the analogy with *scoping* or *shadowing* of variables in programming.

Comment: I was going to recommend Renaud's answer, augmented with my error-checking bits---but the recursive `make` call makes the error checking a little harder...I haven't figured out how to work around that.

Comment: *This example uses `$@` rather than `$*` because it is defined at the time the prerequisites are evaluated*: no, `$@`, just like `$*` is not defined during the first expansion. What you do seems to work because you moved the recipe from the `deploy` rule to the `deploy-%` pattern rule. So `ENVIRONMENT` is expanded in this context.

Comment: I did some testing and you are correct.  It seems to work because the variables that are declared are not expanded until the place where they are used in the recipe.  I need to see if there's a better way to use this new knowledge.

Comment: Yes, recipes are expanded just before being passed to the shell and as you use recursively expanded variables they are expanded at that time, when all automatic variables already have their value. But your idea of moving the recipe to the pattern rule is a good idea anyway. You could even push it a bit further (see my last edit to my own answer).